# How to visibly differentiate Jquery Radio and Checkbox Buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI buttonset for radio groups and checkbox groups. The default styling for both is same, which do not make things obvious for the user whether the option presented is single choice or multiple choices.

Differentiating them by icons is the only workaround? Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: Here are two samples straight from JQUERY UI Demos.
 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio